# How to add class to containing p tag in Joomla TinyMCE

Tags: joomla, tinymce

I am trying to add a class to the containing p tag using the TinyMCE styles.

eg.

```
<p class="text-left">test</p>
```

However, when I select the style from the format drop-down list, an additional span is inserted

```
<p><span class="text-left">test</span></p>
```

I have tried by just clicking in on the text, and also highlighting the text and both insert the additional span.

How can I add a class to the p tag directly without switching to the source code editor?

Comment: Please post Joomla questions on JSE.  I am trying to get more users, questions, activity in the dedicated community -- otherwise it will never grow.